# Run Selenium tests via Jenkins on Docker Django app

Tags: python, django, docker, selenium, jenkins

I would like to run Selenium integration tests on a Development server.
Our App is Django app and it is deployed via Jenkins and Docker.

- We know how to write and run Selenium tests localy
- We know how to run tests with Jenkins and present Cobertura and Junit reports

The problem we have is:

- In order for Selenium tests (apart from unit tests) the server needs to run
- So we can't run tests before we build docker image
- How to run tests inside docker images (this could be potentially achieved via script called inside Dockerfile...)
- BUT even more important: How can Jenkins get the reports from inside docker containers

Whats are the best practice here.

The Deployment structure:

- Jenkins get code from GIT
- Jenkins Builds docker images
- pass this image to the Docker registry (a private one)
- log in to the remote server
- on remote server pull the image from the registry
- run image on a remote server

Comment: Given that deployment structure where exactly would you like to put your tests? As the final step?

Comment: Yes - the Selenium tests needs to be at the end, so that server is running.